# Javascript/ JQuery Deselecting radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have the following javascript, which I want to use to enable the user to deselect a selected radio button by clicking it.  (I know this is not standard, but it is required by the system :)

```
DeselectRadioButton = {
    setup: function () {
        $(".deselectRadioButton").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert("I am checked!");
                ($(this).removeAttr('checked'));
            }
        });
    }
};
```

My issue is that when I select an unselected radio button, it immediately deselects it after the alert shows.

I guess I am receiving the event after the item has changed - how can I fix this code to make my radio button deselectable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, the main issue is that when I
>   select an unselected radio button, it
>   immediately deselects it after the
>   alert shows.

It seems you can't prevent the default behavior of a radio button with either `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` as the radio button always is checked when the click handler is fired.  One way around this was to add a separate class to the radio button and use that as your indicator.

```
$(".deselectRadioButton").click( function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass("on")){
       $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
}).filter(":checked").addClass("on");
```

Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/FaRYg/1/).

Comment: This doesn't work for a group of radio buttons - but you just need to clear the class when another button from the same group is selected.

Answer (score 3):

One of the challenges I found while doing this was with groups of radio buttons.  The solutions provided work splendidly for a single radio button, but in groups I ran into an issue where de-selecting one and then trying to select another failed (until a second click).

I just came across a solution [here](http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2009/6/9/Unselecting-Radio-Buttons-with-jQuery) that's working splendidly:

```
var allRadios = $('input[type=radio]')
var radioChecked;

var setCurrent = function(e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  radioChecked = $(obj).attr('checked');
}

var setCheck = function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'keypress' && e.charCode != 32) {
    return false;
  }
  var obj = e.target;
  if (radioChecked) {
    $(obj).attr('checked', false);
  } else {
    $(obj).attr('checked', true);
  }
}    

$.each(allRadios, function(i, val){        
  var label = $('label[for=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']');

  $(this).bind('mousedown keydown', function(e){
    setCurrent(e);
  });

  label.bind('mousedown keydown', function(e){
    e.target = $('#' + $(this).attr("for"));
    setCurrent(e);
  });

  $(this).bind('click', function(e){
    setCheck(e);    
  });
});
```

Comment: @Brel: Interesting, this code is definitely working on my form.  When the form posts, what values are sent to the server?  You should be able to see them with something like FireBug.

Comment: Not sure what I wrote anymore but I deleted the comment because the code works fine. My problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$(this).removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem David described with groups of radio buttons.  Here's another way around that problem (based on Mark's solution) that works for multiple radio button groups on the same page:

```
$(":radio").click( function(e){
    var itsOn = $(this).hasClass("on");
    $(":radio[name="+ this.name + "]").removeClass("on");
    if(itsOn){
      $(this).removeAttr('checked');
      $(this).siblings().filter("[value='']").attr('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("on");
    }
  }).filter(":checked").addClass("on");
```

Comment: This worked for me. Although I removed the line to check a sibling: $(this).siblings().filter("[value='']").attr('checked', true);

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's nothing else messing with it?

I tried this code, and it works:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input id="one" name="value" type="radio">
        <label for="one">One</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="two" name="value" type="radio">
        <label for="two">Two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="three" name="value" type="radio">
        <label for="three">Three</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(event) {
    // If the button is selected.
    if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
        // Remove the placeholder.
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
        // And remove the selection.
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    // If the button is not selected.
    } else {
        // Remove the placeholder from the other buttons.
        $("input[type='radio']").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
        });
        // And add the placeholder to the button.
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kappa/fD8V9/).

Comment: Thanks for replying - unfortunately this didn't work for me, as it only allowed a single deselect.

Comment: @lainie: I see, I misread your question; I've updated my answer extending Mark's answer, check if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Holy !"#%"# your [jsfiddle has 163 edits](http://jsfiddle.net/kFHsm/163/). Anyway, doesn't work for me.

Comment: @abrkn the Fiddle linked in my answer - http://jsfiddle.net/kFHsm/2/ - works in Firefox 15.0.1, Internet Explorer 8.0.7 and 9.0.8, Chrome 22 and Opera 12.02. Which browser are you using, and what kind of problem are you experiencing?

Comment: If I checked "A" then "B" and then "A", "A" wouldn't become checked. This is my version: http://jsfiddle.net/abrkn/PGW2Z/ , however it doesn't work if you press SPACE to select/deselect.

Comment: @abrkn I've updated the fiddle to fix the problem, this one should handle A-B-A clicks correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/kappa/fD8V9/