# Iterating through the radio button group and prepare a string of selected options

Tags: jquery

I have a test page on which there are a number of questions with 4 options each.

```
<div class="question">
        <p>Who invented C?</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" name="1" value='a'/>A. James Gowsling</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="1" value='b'/>B. Dennis Ritchie</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="1" value='c'/>C. Larry Wall</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="1" value='d'/>D. Bob Peterson</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <p>Who invented Java?</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" name="2" value='a'/>A. James Gowsling</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="2" value='b'/>B. Dennis Ritchie</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="2" value='c'/>C. Larry Wall</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="2" value='d'/>D. Bob Peterson</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to find the options selected by the user (a,b,c or d) and append them and pass as a string to `submitTest.php`.In case he doesn't attempt the question, I want to pass z.
e.g abbzd

I tried this and it works but how can I handle 'not-attempted' question and pass `z` instead.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var string = '';
        $('.question').each(function () {
            $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                    string += $(this).val();
            });
        });
        alert(string);
    });
});
```

Secondly, if a user doesn't want to attempt any question and mistakenly clicks on any option,then he cannot revert back.I mean he is forced to select one of the radio button in the group.How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First probleme

You don't need to iterate into the input, just check if one is selected:

```
$('.question').each(function () {
    string += $(this).find('input:checked').length ? $(this).find('input:checked').val() : 'z';
});
```

## Second one

Use checkbox and this code :

```
$('.question input').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('.question').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
})
```

Comment: :`find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length ` in the first snippet tells whether a radio button is selected or not,and this length can be either 0 or -1 since we can select only one radio button at a time in a radiogroup.Am I right?

Comment: @InsaneCoder Yes and no, it does exactly what you said but give 1 or 0 (not -1). I think you get it!

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant 1 .Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You're already checking for `checked`, so just apply an `else` condition.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        string += $(this).val();
    } else {
        string += 'z';
    }
});
```

Deselecting radio buttons is covered on SO already: [Javascript/ JQuery Deselecting radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246012/javascript-jquery-deselecting-radio-buttons)

Comment: I think it will give me for each question as `zzcz`, `zbzz` and so on

Comment: Isn't that what was asked for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
var a1 = document.querySelector('input[name="1"]:checked');
var b1 = document.querySelector('input[name="2"]:checked');

if (a1 != null)
  a1 = a1.value;
else
  a1 = ‘’;
if (b1 != null)
  b1 = b1.value;
else
   b1 = ‘’;

alert(a1 + ‘ ’ + b1);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery map-function is ideal for this kind of thing. Also I added clear button to clear the answer if the user wants to do that:

Html:

```
<div class="question">
    <p>Who invented C?</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="1" value='a' />A. James Gowsling</li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="1" value='b' />B. Dennis Ritchie</li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="1" value='c' />C. Larry Wall</li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="1" value='d' />D. Bob Peterson</li>
        <li><button class="clear">Clear answer</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var m = $("ul").map(function () {
            var $checked = $(this).find(":radio:checked");
            if ($checked.size() > 0) {
                return $checked.val();
            } else {
                return "z";
            }
        });
        console.log(m);
    });

    $("button.clear").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest("ul").find(":radio").prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```